# Spring boot multi module requires multiple main classes

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a multi-module Spring boot project and am building from maven. I have one Spring boot main class in the first module but am getting build errors from other modules that I don't have a main class in them. Are multiple required?

Comment: When you start a single module with `mvn spring-boot:run` from a command line on its folder, what happens ? Another module is causing trouble ? Can we see a few logs ?

Comment: I figured it out - I had this below in the parent pom file and needed to move it to the pom file of the module that has the main class.                         
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>